# How to stop a query on in an oracle data base

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

We are using oracle > 10.0 here and our software creates different types of reports for evaluation of the stored data. Because of the amount of data it is possible that such a report takes a couple of **minutes** to create and the customers would like to stop the queries.

Is there a way to say the DMBS that it should stop a query? It would also be great to get state information like a count of rows allready read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a blog post from Tanel Poder [here](http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2010/02/17/how-to-cancel-a-query-running-in-another-session/), a call to `DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SWITCH_CONSUMER_GROUP_FOR_SESS (sid, serial#, 'CANCEL_SQL');` (where sid and serial# identify the session to be interrupted) may work, but he's not tested it.

If your application can make `OCICancel()` or jdbc `Statement.cancel` calls, that may work as well.

In either case, I'm not sure how to get a state of rows already read; interrupting a SQL*Plus session that's spooling output will tell you how many rows it has output, but if it hasn't started spooling output, it won't.

Comment: +1 for the link to Tanel's post - I'm going to experiment with this myself, as this could be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a cut-off time (or other resource) limit for the queries, set up Oracle profiles and resource limits and let the RDBMS take care of killing the sessions:  [doc here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/users.htm#15451)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of helpful posts on the CANCEL_SQL approach described by Adam:

http://bitbach.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/implementing-cancel_sql-with-the-resource-manager/

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/ResourceManagerEnhancements10g.php